# Get index of item in bindable collection

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

In this listbox i display contact names.

```
<ListBox x:Name="Items" Margin="36,38,78,131">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lol" Text="{Binding Path=ContactName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"
Width="Auto" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <Button x:Name="ShowName">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="delete" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I get contacts from local DB

```
public List<FBContacts> listContactDatas { get; set; }

Items = new BindableCollection<FBContacts>();= new BindableCollection<FBContacts>();

public void GetContacts()
    {
       using(MyDataContext mydb = new MyDataContext(DBConnectionstring))
       { 
        var items = from ContactsList Name in mydb._contacts select Name;
        foreach (var toDoItem in items)
        {
           Items.Add(new FBContacts()
                {
                    ContactName = toDoItem.Name
                });
        }
        }
    }
```

user can delete any contact if he press button.

```
public void delete()
    {
        Items.RemoveAt(/* index*/);
    }
```

so how i can get index of choosen contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier if you pass the clicked `FBContacts` to `delete` method :

```
<Button x:Name="ShowName">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="delete">
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding}" />
            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Then you can remove by `FBContacts` object instead of index :

```
public void delete(FBContacts item)
{
    Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the currently selected item's index to a separate property:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Items" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedListIndex}" Margin="36,38,78,131">
```

Of course, `SelectedListIndex` must be defined as property of type `int` that fires `PropertyChanged` in the Viewmodel.

Then, you can easily access the selected item's index everywhere within the Viewmodel:

```
public void delete()
{
    Items.RemoveAt(SelectedListIndex);
}
```

Comment: Does the `SelectedListIndex` property get updated when changing the selection (e.g., breakpoint on it's Setter)? Maybe you need to add `SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedListIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"` to force property update

Comment: I get this error

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" in System.Windows.ni.dll

Comment: Maybe the list's selection is changed before `SelectedListIndex` is created. How do you populate the list? Are the list items set through data binding?